# Issues with my Python login script. Invalid syntax on try

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having issues with the current program that I am trying to write. I don't understand why it keeps saying this or why.

Also can this code be extended to cover IP logging and making sure multiple users can be logged in on the same IP in theory?

Here is the code:

```
import hashlib
import time
#cPickle is faster then pickle but not available in all python releases
#thats why i used a try/accept there
try: import cPickle as cp


#load the database if it exist, if not it create one
try:
    f =(r"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\python\database.data")
    data = cp.load(f)
except IOError:
    data = {}

#A simple function made to make data dumping easy
def easyDump(data_):
    f = file(r"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\python\database.data", "w")
    cp.dump(data_, f)
    f.close()

#Get's the date (We'll use this as the custom salt)
def getData():
    return str(time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))

#A function which accepts two parameters, password and date.
#The date is the custom salt. It returns the sha512 hash excetpyion
def  salt(password, date):
    salted = hasglib.sha512(password + str(data)).hexdigest()
    retun str(salted)

menu = """"
1.Login
2.Register
3.Exit
"""

while True:
    print menu
    choice = int(raw_input("Your choice please: "))
    if choice ==1:
        username = raw_input("Enter your username please: ")
        password = raw.input("Enter your authentication code please: ")
        #if the username is found on the database
        if data.has_key(username):
            #date is equal to our secured stored data
            date = date[username][1]
            #check of the given password  + date is equal to what is stored on the database
            #password
            if salt(password, date) == date[username][0]:
                print"Welcome %s!" % username
            else:
                print "Incorrect password"
            else:
                print "user %s not found, please register!" % username
        elif choice == 2:
            username = raw_input("Please enter yout username: !")
            password = raw_input("Please enter your password: !")
            #if username exists in the system already then the name is taken
            if data.has_key(username):
                print "user %s already registered, please put in another % username
            else:
                #in order words data = {username: hash, date}
                data[username] = [salt(password, getData()), get Data()]
                easyDump(data)
                print "user %s successfully registereed!" %username
            elif choice == 3:
                print "goodbye!"
                break
            else:
                print "invaid input or commands"
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
try: import cPickle as cp
```

is not followed by an `except` ... hence the syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains many indenting, syntax errors and spelling mistakes. The following fixes these to allow it to at least run:

```
import hashlib
import time

#cPickle is faster then pickle but not available in all Python releases
#That is why I used a try/accept there
try: 
    import cPickle as cp
except:
    import pickle as cp

#load the database if it exist, if not it create one
try:
    f = open(r"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\python\database.data")
    data = cp.load(f)
except IOError:
    data = {}

#A simple function made to make data dumping easy
def easyDump(data_):
    f = file(r"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\python\database.data", "w")
    cp.dump(data_, f)
    f.close()

#Get's the date (We'll use this as the custom salt)
def getData():
    return str(time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))

#A function which accepts two parameters, password and date.
#The date is the custom salt. It returns the sha512 hash exception
def salt(password, date):
    salted = hasglib.sha512(password + str(data)).hexdigest()
    return str(salted)      

menu = """"
1.Login
2.Register
3.Exit
"""

while True:
    print menu
    choice = int(raw_input("Your choice please: "))
    if choice == 1:
        username = raw_input("Enter your username please: ")
        password = raw.input("Enter your authentication code please: ")
        #if the username is found on the database
        if data.has_key(username):
            #date is equal to our secured stored data
            date = date[username][1]
            #check of the given password  + date is equal to what is stored on the database
            #password
            if salt(password, date) == date[username][0]:
                print"Welcome %s!" % username
            else:
                print "Incorrect password"
        else:
            print "user %s not found, please register!" % username
    elif choice == 2:
        username = raw_input("Please enter yout username: !")
        password = raw_input("Please enter your password: !")
        #if username exists in the system already then the name is taken
        if data.has_key(username):
            print "user %s already registered, please put in another" % username
        else:
            #in order words data = {username: hash, date}
            data[username] = [salt(password, getData()), getData()]
            easyDump(data)
            print "user %s successfully registered!" % username
    elif choice == 3:
        print "goodbye!"
        break
    else:
        print "invalid input or commands"
```

Indenting in Python is very important, getting it wrong can completely change the meaning of the code.